# formatting SAS e-mailing with carriage return

Tags: email, sas, carriage-return

I am trying to output a carriage return with the PUT command, but I cannot do it. Here is an example of my e-mail code at the moment.

```
data _null_;
     file tmp;
     put "Hello, \n \n";
     put "This is a test of carriage return.";
run;

Filename tmp Email
Subject="SAS email"
To = ("myself@website.com")
CT = "text/html";
```

However, the received email looks like this:

> Hello, \n \n This is a test of carriage return.

Comment: This isn't actually very much related to my last question @superfluous

Comment: Sorry, I somehow got confused as to which page I was on. Glad the answer worked for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a forward slash for this:

```
data _null_;
     put "Hello," / /;
     put "This is a test of carriage return.";
run;
```

Documented [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000161869.htm), under the forward slash line pointer control.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a HTML formatted email you can also use `<BR>` or `<P>` tags. e.g.

```
put "<BR>";
```